# Isolated Gradle Tasks?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to port over a somewhat convoluted Makefile to Gradle. I need to be able to have some tasks that execute in isolation of each other, but I cannot figure out how to do this in Gradle; for example, if I have a build.gradle that looks like the following:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

task foo {
  println 'foo'
}

task bar {
  println 'bar'
}

task baz {
  println 'baz'
}
```

If I run:

> gradle -q foo

Then I expect to see

> foo

But instead I see:

> foobarbaz

printed to my terminal.

How can I configure Gradle to only perform the single task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't given the tasks any functionality; what you're seeing is the output of the tasks being instantiated.

Change your build.gradle to this...

```
task foo {
  doLast {
    println 'foo'
  }
}

task bar << {
  println 'bar'
}

task baz {
  println 'baz'
}
```

and then run the foo task:

`gradle foo`

Your output should be...

```
baz
:foo
foo
```

...showing that baz was output when the baz task was created, then the foo task was executed (":foo") followed by the output of the foo task. Note that the "<<" operator is an alias for doLast.

See [Build Script Basics](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) in the Gradle User Guide.